# How to open a port of kafka at GCP server for a AWS ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka

I want to connect to a kafka deployed on GCP server from AWS's ec2 server.

I am able to connect to the GCP server's port from within GCP server network(default), but i am unable to connect with the AWS server which is outside the network.

I have made a service account on GCP, but how can i integrate it with AWS?

Comment: Unclear what firewall settings or port openings on the VPC you've already done... Google documentation shows you how to open up and forward network traffic. If you've having issues beyond that,  networking infrastructure should be asked on https://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that under the firewall section you have allowed kafka default port 9092.
Also confirm about zookeeper default ports:-

2181 for client connections;
2888 for follower(other zookeeper nodes) connections;
3888 for inter nodes connections.

Need more clarity on below:

1. How are you exposing GCP VM instances to external networks? Is the connection happening over the internet or via VPN ?
2. If the intention is to use Workload Identity Federation to grant on-premises or multi-cloud (aws in this case)  workloads access to Google Cloud resources?
   Please go through the google documentation [1] and [2].

[1]https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation
[2] https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/access-resources-aws